# How to get Server Home directory path in tomcat in spring bean configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jboss

I have a web application running in tomcat. I have some properties in a file.

currently I am using absolute path to file in bean configuration like this.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="com.RAPropertyUtil">
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:/home/user/config/application.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I want to make it relative to server home directory something like that.

```
<value>${server.home}/conf/application.properties</value>
```

Also could I make to server independent, like if I can get home directory of any server Tomcat or JBOSS, I don't have to change this configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similar case might help:

```
file:${user.home}/.conf/${my.app.environment}/application-additional.properties
```

Also i have application.properties in `src/main/resources` where hold default value

```
my.app.environment=dev
```

and when i need another environment, i just pass VM argument like:

```
-Dmy.app.environment=prod
```

Comment: Currently I am using ${user.home}, but with this I have to put configuration file relative to user home and It changes with the way I start tomcat. If I start tomcat from bin directory (run startup.sh) , user home becomes bin/. If I make server of tomcat and run service from home (user home in bash), user home will become /home/user_name. If I run service from root, it becomes relative to root. I am trying to solve this problem here.

Comment: i meant when you use this -> `${server.home}/conf/application.properties` path VM argument to tomcat like `-Dserver.home=path/to/config`